# Calling block of code from the command line

Tags: perl

I have a block of code that I need to run only when I enter the procedure name in the command line. Is it possible to do this? Also , is it possible to pass arguments to a subroutine from the command line.

Comment: Please post your code.   (See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @BadZen The OP doesn't know how to do this, so any code he has would be irrelevant clutter. It only makes sense to ask for people's code when they're debugging a specific issue.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot - Quick, is OP talking about running a subroutine by name, enabling a block of code as an option, accepting the name of a routine on stdin, or giving it as an argument?   Is he C&P'ing from an example from somewhere else and modifying it?  Is his "block of code" a Perl `sub` or an actual block?  Does he want it to "only run" as an optional branch during a procedural execution, or as a cli dispatch? Definitely determine all those things just from what is written above and then communicate the answer back to him without a concrete example.  Just vaguely describe it in words.

Comment: Make a module with your block and use it -- `perl -MModName=proc -e 'proc(...)';`  Is this what you are asking about?